# Sails.js - Relate 3 models

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sails.js

Seller.js

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name: 'string',
    fantasy_name: 'string',
    email: 'string',
    password: 'string',
    status: 'boolean',

    store: {
      collection: 'store',
      via: 'fk_seller'
    }
  }
};
```

Store.js

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name: 'string',
    state: 'string',
    city: 'string',
    neighborhood: 'string',
    fk_seller: {
      model: 'seller'
    },

    product: {
      collection: 'product',
      via: 'fk_store'
    }
  }
};
```

Product.js

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name: 'string',
    price: 'string',
    fk_store: {
      model: 'store'
    }
  }
};
```

How do i relate this 3 models to do one select, like this sql command?

```
select a.name, b.state, c.price from seller a inner join store b on a.id = b.fk_seller inner join product c on b.id = c.fk_store
```

with 2 models i can do what i want, but with 3 models it's complicate:

```
Product.find().populate('fk_store').exec(console.log) //ok
```

sorry, for my bad english.